# System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Tags: c#

```
string[] rounds = cols[5].Split('|');

foreach (string round in rounds)
{
    //splitting each round on "^"
    string[] msText = round.Split('^');

    //create a new list in text file
    List<MatchupModel> ms = new List<MatchupModel>();

    foreach (string matchupModelTextId in msText)
    {
        // this is the line on which I am getting the error
        ms.Add(matchups.Where(x => x.Id == int.Parse(matchupModelTextId)).First());
    }

    tm.Rounds.Add(ms);
}
```

Comment: According to [MSDN Int.Parse documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) this can happen if the string is not in the correct format (see sections 'Exception' and 'Remarks'). Did you verify that matchupModelTextId contains a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this - see if `matchupModelTextId` can be interpreted as an integer, and only if it can, have it add matchups;

```
foreach (string matchupModelTextId in msText)
{
    int matchupId;
    if (int.tryParse(matchupModelTextId, out matchupId)) {
        ms.Add(matchups.Where(x => x.Id == matchupId).First());
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much sir, i worked like a charm. you saved me from rewriting my whole project.:)